# Bootstrap subtheme does not recognize stylesheets

Tags: theming

I'm trying to use a custom (LESS) build of Bootstrap in my Drupal project. I have a subtheme in the proper folder and have compiled a style.css file. However, Drupal does not recognize this file. So far I have

- Edited the .info file to switch of the CDN and switch on the local .js files
- Cleared the cache
- Switched off the aggregation of CSS
- Restarted the server
- Added a foo.css to the .info file for testing

Nothing of this works. The subtheme does not recognize my custom css files.

What could have gone wrong here?

Comment: does the subtheme otherwise work? can you post the .info file for both the main and sub-theme, and the most painfully obvious question - have you enabled the subtheme and set it active (default perhaps)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to turn the subtheme on in the theme settings.